# Deleting contacts in bulk - Ice cream sandwich

Tags: contacts, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, delete

I just got my Galaxy Nexus, and from logging into some service, I can't figure out which,
it automatically imported contacts which I don't want on the phone. Is there a way to delete contacts in bulk? I haven't found one yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for android 4.0

settings--->storage--->Apps--->Contacts Storage--->clear data

sync the contacts with your gmail account before doing this, remove synchornisation, do the above steps and sync again with you gmail account, will take some time for the names and numbers to come